# Entity Framework 6 Update Many to Many without updating or loading Child

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I want to Update a Record that has a many to many relationship with other records.
My Problem is, that it always tries to also Update its children, which fails because the child has required fields and I only provide the ID.

I dont want to load the child-objects. I just want it to insert the Address and update the many-to-many table.

Address has an IEnumerable, that contains the ProductIDs, the other fields are empty or have the default value(ints an bools).

I get the following Error:

> Property: Name Error: Please enter a Name  Property: Description
>   Error: Please enter a Description  Property: Category Error: Please
>   enter a Category

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReceiveOrder(Address address)
    {
        EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

            context.Addresses.Add(address);
            context.SaveChanges();
            context.Dispose();
            return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Okay" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Address class:

```
    public class Address
{
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public bool Giftwrap { get; set; }
}
```

Product class

```
public class Product
{

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue =false)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter a Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

How do I tell EF that its only supposed to Insert Address and update the relationsship Table. I don't want to generate Overhead by loading Products first. I also dislike accessing the Products table when its not necessary.

Comment: Have you got lazy loading turned off

Comment: i have tried putting `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` in there, but no effect

Comment: I'm wondering if it's because you haven't normalised the tables. Normally in a many-to-many relationship you would have a link table. I think if you introduce the link table, then this may solve the issue. The other thing is, in General if you always have lazy loading set to false, then remove the keyword virtual from the class this sometimes causes these issues.

Comment: I don't know if the table is normalized, I assume it is what ever the EF standard is, because I didnt make ajustments. I've tried removing "virtual" from the properties but the issue remains. I have a link table, it was automatically created by EF

Comment: imho the next error is a duplication key error. You are re-inserting a product.

Comment: I'ts no duplication error, if i load all the products, add them to the address and then write it down, it works. Its really about the missing required fields. But loading them is not what I want, later I'm gonna have a lot of relatet records on many tables, it would generate a serious amount of overhead loadong them all.

Comment: Please see the answer: to avoid loading you should use `Attach`

Comment: Ok the other issue here seems to be that you are mixing both the data object with the object used for your view. You need to separate the two. Your data object can have virtual, but remove all the data annotations. Create a new ViewModal class for your view and remove virtual and just make it a plain list. To prove the point just for now remove the data annotations and try saving again, Your mapping file should take care of required etc at the backend. In a production environment you would have a data repository for the EF stuff. The controllers used as a 'switching' service between the layers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use:

- [Attach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.attach%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method (DbSet) to activate the modification tracking.

> Attach is used to repopulate a context with an entity that is known to
>   already exist in the database

- [Entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696578%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method (DbContext) to be able to set the Status of the attached entity.

You may alsa want to read [Add/Attach and Entity States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx)

for many products:

```
public ActionResult ReceiveOrder(Address address)
{
    EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    context.Set<Addresses>().Attach(address);
    foreach(Product p in address.Products) {
        context.Set<Products>().Attach(p);
    }
    context.Entry(address).State = EntityState.Added; 

    context.SaveChanges();
    context.Dispose();
    return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Okay" },
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Neither has Address a `Single()` Method nor has context an `Attach()` Method. I'm not clear what you are trying to do. It also seems you are trying to attach only one Product, wouldn't that have to go in a foreach loop? And you are clearing `address.Products`, doesn't that remove all relationships?

Comment: if you have more than one product, indeed you must use a loop for attach then add. In this case you may attach every entity the set the sate of address as added

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm and die SQL statement looks very clean. Just what I wanted. Last question: Would this approach delete already existing references between these two objects or does it just add new ones?

Comment: It does just add new ones. But you may delete by using `EntityState.Deleted` for example.